# “required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]” error from this for-comprehension

Tags: scala, future

I’m a new scala developer kind of bogged down with a type problem. Sometimes I’m still tripped up by handling futures, and I think this is one of those times. This section of code…

```
// do some stuff with a collection of List[Future[ClientArticle]]
Future.sequence(listFutureClonedArticles).map( clonedArticles =>
    for {
        // create persistent records of the cloned client articles, and discard the response
        _ <- clonedArticles.map(clonedArticle => clientArticleDAO.create(clonedArticle))

        // add cloned articles to a batch of articles, and discard the response
        _ <- batchDAO.addArticlesToExistingBatch(destinationBatch._id, clonedArticles.map(_._id))

    } yield {

        // ultimately just return the cloned articles
        clonedArticles
    }
)
```

… is producing this compiler error:

```
[error] /.../app/services/BatchServiceAPI.scala:442: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[List[model.ClientArticle]]
[error]  required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
[error]                             _ <- batchDAO.addArticlesToExistingBatch(destinationBatch._id, clonedArticles.map(_._id))
[error]                               ^
```

The arguments to addArticlesToExistingBatch() appear to be the correct type for the method signature:

```
/** Adds a list of id's to a batch by it's database ID. */
def addArticlesToExistingBatch(batchId: ID, articleIds: List[ID])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Return]
```

Of course, I might be misunderstanding how a for comprehension works too. I don’t understand how an error can occur at the <- operator, nor how/why there would be type expectations at that point.

Can anyone help me understand what needs to be done here?

**=== 21 minutes later... ===**

Interesting.  When I stop using the for comprehension and break these out into two separate maps, it compiles.

```
// create cloned client articles
Future.sequence(listFutureClonedArticles).map(clonedArticles =>
    clonedArticles.map(clonedArticle => clientArticleDAO.create(clonedArticle)))

// add cloned articles to destination batch
Future.sequence(listFutureClonedArticles).map(clonedArticles =>
    batchDAO.addArticlesToExistingBatch(destinationBatch._id, clonedArticles.map(_._id)))
```

So yeah, I guess I still don't quite understand for-comprehensions.  I thought they could be used to roll up several Future operations.  Why doesn't that work in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for comprehension is a combination of `flatMap` and `map`. Every line with `<-` is converted into a `flatMap` but the last line which is converted to a `map`.

So, you code

```
  for {
    // create persistent records of the cloned client articles, and discard the response
    _ <- clonedArticles.map(clonedArticle => clientArticleDAO.create(clonedArticle))
    // add cloned articles to a batch of articles, and discard the response
    _ <- batchDAO.addArticlesToExistingBatch(destinationBatch._id, clonedArticles.map(_._id))
  } yield {
    // ultimately just return the cloned articles
    clonedArticles
  }
```

is converted to

```
  clonedArticles.map(clonedArticle => clientArticleDAO.create(clonedArticle)).flatMap { _ =>
    batchDAO.addArticlesToExistingBatch(destinationBatch._id, clonedArticles.map(_._id)).map { _ =>
      clonedArticles
    }
  }
```

as `clonedArticles` is a `List` and the signature for `flatMap` for the list is

```
final override def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = ???
```

If you look at the parameter required by `flatMap` it needs a function `A => GenTraversableOnce` but in your function you are passing a function `A => Future` that is the problem.

I have tried to imitate your problem with simple functions you can try that:

```
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  val listOfFuture: List[Future[Int]] = (1 to 10).map(Future(_)).toList
  def f(i: List[Int]): Future[String] = Future(s"very complex logic: ${i.sum}")
  def create(i: Int): Future[Unit] = Future(println(s"creating something complex: $i"))

 Future.traverse(listOfFuture){ futureX =>
   for {
     x <- futureX
     _ <- create(x)
   } yield x
  }.flatMap(f)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also found someone else's summary useful: _"The key thing is that, in a for comprehension, all of the types on the right-hand side of the arrows have to be the same."_